# Does not add items to ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arrays, list, android-arrayadapter, adapter

So I have this code:

```
   suggestionsAdapter.clear();
                locations.clear();
                List<Predictions> predictions = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getJSONArray("predictions").toString(), new TypeToken<List<Predictions>>(){}.getType());
                for(Predictions prediction : predictions){
                    String title = prediction.terms.get(0).value;
                    locations.add(title);
                    suggestionsAdapter.add(title);
                }
                Log.i("","loc are:" + locations);
                Log.i("","locations are:" + locations.size());
                suggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i("","suggestion adapter size:" + suggestionsAdapter.getCount());
```

And I get back this:

```
 03-30 10:55:56.474: I/(3185): loc are:[Albert Cuypstraat, Albert Cuyp Market, Albania, Alblasserdam, Albert Cuypstraat]
 03-30 10:55:56.474: I/(3185): locations are:5
 03-30 10:55:56.474: I/(3185): suggestion adapter size:0
```

Why is this happening?
PS: this happens inside a listener that gets back the predictions from a google places query.
Changed to:

```
 suggestionsAdapter.addAll(locations);
                        suggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Still same result, sometimes I get:

```
 03-30 11:03:25.876: I/(10409): loc are:[Albert Cuypstraat, Albert Cuyp Market, Albert Cuypstraat, AH Haarlemmerdijk, Albert Heijn]
 03-30 11:03:25.876: I/(10409): locations are:5
 03-30 11:03:25.876: I/(10409): suggestion adapter size:3
```

Comment: why you adding one by one title in   suggestionsAdapter.add(...) ?

Comment: Cause I was getting the same result for  suggestionsAdapter.addAll(locations); And I said I will try to add them individually

Comment: just call `notifyDataSetChanged();` inside `suggestionsAdapter.add(...)`

Comment: It is an ArrayAdapter. I need it to be an ArrayAdapter for the AutoCompletionTextView. Also I did a notifyDataSetChanged in a postDelayed runnable (500ms), and I get the same thing...

Comment: you still do not understand what i said? post your all ArrayAdapter code

Comment: It is an array adapter, as in:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html
ArrayAdapter suggestionsAdapter; (AKA It is not custom, it's part of the Android SDK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the list for a AutoCompleteTextView. And that was the issue. when loading the list, the AutoCompleteTextView was filtering, hence why it would not show responses.
I fixed this using a custom autoCompleteTextView, which I took from here:
https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite.html